# Компиляция optipng

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

добрый вечер! Существует проект [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/), который использует для работы [zlib](https://github.com/madler/zlib). Как я понимаю, скорость работы zlib можно существенно повысить благодаря использованию [masmx86](https://github.com/madler/zlib/tree/master/contrib/masmx86). подскажите, пожалуйста. как можно компилировать OptiPNG с использованием masmx86? Есть готовые файлы inffas32.obj match686.obj.

Comment: "*скорость работы zlib можно существенно повысить*"... повысить - может быть (но не факт), существеннно - вряд ли. "*как можно компилировать OptiPNG с использованием masmx86*" ... это написано в ридми по вашей ссылке, текст которого выведен на первой же странице.

Comment: Мне просто не понятно, как использовать masmx86 пр компиляции OptiPNG. можно поподробнее?

Comment: Эти obj нужно использовать для сборки zlib, с которой уже потом собирается всё остальное. Как - см. по ссылке, со слов "Build instructions".

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас попробую